# Trouble opening new program in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recently downloaded Android Studio and attempted to open a new project.  The code that is generated looks like this:

```
package com.example.trevo.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GettingStarted extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_getting_started);
    }
}
```

The tabs at the top of my screen (scr, main, java, com, example, trevo, myapplication, GettingStarted) are all underlined in red.  Also the 'R' in the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_getting_started);` is red and gets the error "cannot resolve symbol".  When I try to run the program as written I get the following error.

```
C:\Users\trevo\Documents\Java4Android_Projects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_getting_started.xml

Error:(13, 49) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' with value 'parent').

Error:(14, 45) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' with value 'parent').

Error:(15, 47) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' with value 'parent').

Error:(16, 43) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' with value 'parent').

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Has anyone else had this problem with Android Studio?  What can I do to remedy these errors?

Comment: Just Clean and Rebuild through Build Options on the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Android Studio, happened to my build too.

To resolve it, Clean Build the project and remove the import which has **R** in it, Android Studio will then import the correct **R**

This issue seems to be resolved in the latest 3.0 RC build

Comment: how do I remove the import which has R in it?

Comment: Simply delete the line, and Android Studio will add the correct line automatically. If it does not import then when the error shows, simply press alt + return key and it will show list of all R, then simply select the correct import